# How to set invisible layout to visible permanently?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

In my application, On the MainActivity.java I need to display two layouts, One is visible in the initial stage and the other is invisible. When a button is pressed the invisible one get visible and visible one get invisible, here is the code i have writen:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment1;
FusedLocationProviderClient client;
View checkoutLayout, checkinLayout;
ImageButton checking_button, checkout_button;
Chronometer chronometer;
Handler handler;
long tMillisec, tStart, tBuff, tUpdate = 0L;
int sec, min, millisec, hr;
TextView tv_location, editText_remark, location_checkout, location_remark, dateView, timeView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());


    checking_button = findViewById(R.id.checkin_btn);
    chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chrono);
    checkoutLayout = findViewById(R.id.checkOut);
    checkinLayout = findViewById(R.id.checkinLayout);
    checkout_button = findViewById(R.id.checkout_btn);
    tv_location = findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
    editText_remark = findViewById(R.id.editText_remark);
    location_checkout = findViewById(R.id.location_checkout);
    location_remark = findViewById(R.id.Remark_checkout);
    dateView = findViewById(R.id.date_pick);
    timeView = findViewById(R.id.time_pick);


    checkinLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    checkoutLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    handler = new Handler();

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map_view);
    supportMapFragment1 = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_view1);
    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    // check permission

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        // when permission granted call method
        getCurrentLocation();
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);
    }

    checking_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(tv_location.getText().toString().isEmpty() || editText_remark.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter your Location and Remark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                checkoutLayout.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                checkinLayout.setVisibility(v.GONE);
                tStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
                chronometer.start();
                location_checkout.setText(tv_location.getText().toString());
                location_remark.setText(editText_remark.getText().toString());
                dateView.setText("Date:"+ date);
                timeView.setText("Punch-In:"+ currentTime);
            }
        }
    });

    checkout_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkinLayout.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
            checkoutLayout.setVisibility(v.GONE);
        }
    });


}
```

The code works good but the problem is when i make checkoutLayot visible and checkinLayout invisible, when i close the app and reopen it the layout changes to checkoutLayout invisible and checkinLayout visible, So i need to make the last visited page visible. I am new to android development, can any one help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `SharePreference` for this, to save the state that your app was in when the user closed the app. Save the state in the sharedpreference as soon as user presses a button and then in `onStart` method of the app, you can get the value of the state from the `SharePreference` and then show your layouts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first you should put all your variables including views(like Textview, Handler etc. private). Secondly our friend @rootass here is right you should use `SharePrference` so you can save changes. Here is an example of writing and getting `SharedPreferences`. Code for Wrting SharedPreferences ...

```
private SharedPreferences visibilityPreference;
private SharedPreferences.Editor prefEdit;
private final String visibilityKey = "visibility";


private void setVisibility(boolean flag){
  prefEdit = visibilityPreference.edit();
  visibilityPreference = context.getSharedPreferences(visibilityPreferenceName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  visibilityPreference.putBoolean(visibilityKey, flag);
  prefEdit.apply();
}
```

And here code for reading SharedPreferences...

```
private boolean getVisibility(){
  visibilityPreference = context.getSharedPreferences(visibilityPreferenceName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  return visibilityPreference .getBoolean(visibilityKey, false); //we set false as default value
}
```

ps : since you are new to android i probably should mention that instead of `context` in mentioned code above if you are in independtend activity you do not need to use context just put `this` or nothing and of you are not in an independent activity, in case of [fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments) use `context` or  `requireActivity()` and in case of being in [recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) use passed `context`.

Hope it helps you ;)